# Attaching plugin to a model programmatically

Tags: gazebo-model, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible to attach plugin to a model directly from the code (not in the sdf files or xml files). So I want to add the model programmatically inside the simulation and then attach a  model plugin to that model by specifying the path to the plugin library.

Something like:

//load model

worldPtr_->InsertModelFile(modelName);

//get model pointer

modelPtr = getModelPtr();

//attach a plugin to that model

attachPlugin(modelPtr, pluginName)

The code above should be executed inside the world plugin. Is something like that even possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16315/attaching-plugin-to-a-model-programmatically/) by [jelavice](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3256/jelavice/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This can be done by manually calling the function "Create" with prototype static TPtr Create( const std::string &  _filename, const std::string & _name). This function is defined in the ModelPlugin.hh header. After that, the "Load" function with prototype void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/) should be called.

This will load the plugin dynamically and register it to the gazebo server.

---

Originally posted by [jelavice](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3256/jelavice/) with karma: 5 on 2017-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0